# How can I remove any additional styling polymer adds for paper-tabs with the link tag?

Tags: css, polymer

Right now I have these two tab groups

```
<paper-tabs id="scrollableTabs" selected="2" scrollable link>
  <paper-tab> <a href="#link1">1</a> </paper-tab>
  <paper-tab> <a href="#link2">2</a> </paper-tab>
  <paper-tab> <a href="#link3">3</a> </paper-tab>
  <paper-tab> <a href="#top">Top</a> </paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

<paper-tabs id="scrollableTabs" selected="2" scrollable >
  <paper-tab>1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>3</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>Top</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

Which gives me a look like this that I don't like and much rather prefer the non link-able style.

[image: Normal comparison]

After futzing around a bit with the css like this

```
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
```

gives me this which is much better but I can't get the padding to work since I assume when using the link property padding is specified within the paper-tabs element.

[image]

So, is there any way to get rid of the styles that the anchor tag adds in the polymer paper tabs group when using the link property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links looks higher 'cause they take up 100% space because of the following CSS.

```
::content > a {
    height: 100%;
}
```

So, by setting the `height` back to the default `auto` should fix it.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Or if you don't feel like using `!important`, you can use either `/deep/` or `::shadow` to update the Shadow DOM CSS. Here's an example using the latter.

```
paper-tab::shadow ::content > a {
    height: auto;
}
```

In Firefox, above `::shadow` code wouldn't work, instead you could do

```
paper-tab .tab-content > a {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the element docs:

> To use links in tabs, add link attribute to paper-tab and put an 
>   element in paper-tab with a tabindex of -1.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <style is="custom-style">
>   .link {
>     @apply(--layout-horizontal);
>     @apply(--layout-center-center);
>   }
> </style>
>
> <paper-tabs selected="0">
>   <paper-tab link>
>     <a href="#link1" class="link" tabindex="-1">TAB ONE</a>
>   </paper-tab>
>   <paper-tab link>
>     <a href="#link2" class="link" tabindex="-1">TAB TWO</a>
>   </paper-tab>
>   <paper-tab link>
>     <a href="#link3" class="link" tabindex="-1">TAB THREE</a>
>   </paper-tab>
> </paper-tabs>
> ```

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs